# Repository is not clean

Tags: git, typescript, github, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

Updating angular 7 to angular 8, I updated successfully upto `angular/cli angular/core` using the command `$ ng update @angular/cli@v8 @angular/core@v8`.
And i used angular material also, so i want to update material then i update with `$ ng update @angular/material@v8`.
But after running the command i got `Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating.`

So I committed before changes to git, then again I tried with the same command, then also getting the same message. Now there are no files to commit or stash.

This is the dependencies of the `package.json` files:
`"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^8.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ngx-loading": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "6.5.2",
    "underscore": "^1.9.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.800.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-scss-preprocessor": "^3.0.0",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~3.4.5"
  }`

This is the message i got:
`D:\test>ng update @angular/material@v8
Repository is not clean.  Please commit or stash any changes before updating.`

I delete the node_modules folder and reinstalled with the help of `$ npm install --save`. After installed i tried again, then also getting the same message.

Does anyone know, how to update the material?

Comment: you must have other changes done to your files, node_modules should never be committed to git, what do you get after running `git status`?

Comment: it's showing few files under the `Untracked files:`, I think those files are no need to committ to git.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You mentioned that you have untracked files. These are causing the check to fail (a git repository with untracked files is considered unclean). More about this [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155046/determine-if-git-working-directory-is-clean-from-a-script).

You can see how the `ng` tool runs this check here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/3d25d4cb/packages/angular/cli/commands/update-impl.ts#L351

You can stash these files with:

```
git stash save --include-untracked
```

And unstash them after running the update with:

```
git stash pop
```

Your other options are to delete the files or add them to your `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `--allow-dirty` if you want to bypass that warning, it works on @angular/cli v8.0.1+.

Your command for updating `@angular/material` would look like the following:

```
ng update @angular/material@v8 --allow-dirty
```

For updating all packages you can use:

```
ng update -all --allow-dirty
```

Answer (score 0):

Run `git reset --hard` or `git stash` and try again.